# Migrating from mysql to postgresql in code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, codeigniter

I am trying to migrate from mysql to postgres in codeigniter. I have updated my database.php file

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb';

$db['default']['username'] = 'postgres';

$db['default']['password'] = 'myPass23';

$db['default']['database'] = 'mydb';



$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
```

I am getting a blank page whenever db call is being made after the migration. No error/No logs are being shown. Do I need to make the changes anywhere else too. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you have missed `$` in first line. Is it copy paste mistake??

Comment: yes thats a copy paste mistake sorry,

Comment: have you enabled error reporting??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these settings with `postgres`

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'postgres'; # Mysql name
$db['default']['password'] = 'myPass23'; # Mysql password
$db['default']['database'] = 'mydb'; # databse name
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'postgre'; # chnage this
```

Some Useful [link](https://codezone4.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/codeigniter-configuration-for-postgresql-database/)